# Let $a,b,c\in\mathbb{C}$ be the roots of $2X^3-2X^2+4X+1$...

Tags: polynomials, complex-numbers, roots

Let $a,b,c\in\mathbb{C}$ be the roots of $2X^3-2X^2+4X+1$.
Find: (1) $a+b+c$, (2) $ab+ac+bc$ and (3) $abc$.

I wish I could provide a starting point here, but honestly I have no idea where to begin. I looked up the roots on Wolfram Alpha and they're impossibly complex. Likewise, according to Wolfram Alpha, $a+b+c=1.5$ and $abc=-0.5$.

Any push in the right direction would be much appreciated.

Comment: Are you familiar with vieta's formulas?  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vieta%27s_formulas

Comment: What Yorch said. Or just expand $2(X-a)(X-b)(X-c)$ to see what's going on.

Comment: As Yorch and Jyrki said, you can use Viéte's Formulas (I'm not sure if I spelled correctly); apart from that, the sum of roots should be $1$ and not $1.5$, which you will see once you solve.

Comment: @ultralegend5385 No, I believe $1.5$ is the right answer.

Comment: @BrianKo14: I see now, no one is at fault; you accidentally typed $\color{red}{2}x^2$ instead of $\color{green}{3}x^2$.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is a good starting point. If a cubic polynomial has roots $a,b,c$ then that polynomial can be written in the form
$$p(X) = C (X-a)(X-b)(X-c)
$$
Now expand this polynomial, and match the result with the given polynomial.

Comment: All right. How didn't I think of that before. Thank you! This will help me solve other problems as well! So: $f=CX^3-C(a+b+c)X^2+C(ac+bc+ab)X-Cabc=2X^3-3X^2+4X+1$. $C=2$, so $a+b+c=3/2$, $ac+bc+ab=2$ and $abc=-1/2$.

Comment: That's correct.